# How to figure out what is running on my (NVIDIA) GPU?

Tags: cuda, deep-learning, gpu, tensorflow

I am using my GPU (Tesla K80) to train neural networks using tensorflow, and something has gone wrong. When I type `nvidia-smi` I see that `11239MiB / 11439MiB` of the memory is being used, but no processes are listed for the GPU.
Normally when this happens I can type `ps aux | grep python` and find the process that is using up the GPU, but this time nothing is coming up.

How do I figure out what is running on my GPU, and how do I kill it?

Comment: I do not know if this is possible on your machine, but on our servers, if nvidia-smi is acting strangely it is time for a restart. Updates are a common cause for nvidia-smi showing strange information, like no Graphics card or no processes or something like this.

Comment: Restart did fix it, but I was hoping for a more elegant, less intrusive solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See all processes being run by the user who used the GPU. Kill all processes that may have used the GPU.

```
ps -ef | grep <username>
```

You could also try

```
sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset
```

If nothing works then consider rebooting.